# How can see git push history date, not commit date

Tags: git, github, gitlab

```
git reflog
```

How to see git push date, not commit date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git reflog --grep-reflog=push origin/master
```

To see pushes of branch `master` to remote `origin` (actually to see the moves of the remote-tracking reference `origin/master` caused by pushes).